# Getting message exist in console while UID is not in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sails.js

I am trying to check if the UID exists in db. If it exist I want it not to write a data else write a data.

But for some reason I am getting exist when there is no such UID.

[image]

```
async function engagements(){
    // const db =  ;
    if (await Engagements.find({uid:"f60c7612-93f5-48b6-8039-94cf5668f6b4"})) {
        console.log("exist");
    }else{
        console.log("does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: check if it is sending an empty array or something

Comment: Store the result in a variable and log it. The fact that your code logs "exist" does not mean the engagement exists, it just means that the resolved Promise is truthy.

Comment: @cmgchess I just got an answer. You are right, it sends an empty array and array is equal to true...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The case that .find() returns an empty array which is equal to true.
Basically I made a const and checked the array if it is empty or not

```
const db =  await Engagements.find({uid:"f60c7612-93f5-48b6-8039-94cf5668f6b4"});
    if (db.length > 0) {
        console.log("exist");
    }else{
        console.log("does not exist");
    }
```